# jQuery display selected option text from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

When I select a option in my drop down list I want to display that selected option in the drop down list, after I have been redirected to another page. The problem I have is that I use the code bellow to be able to redirect to another page when selecting a option from the drop down list.

```
jQuery("#date-version").change(function(event) {
    alert("You have Selected ?version=  :: " + jQuery(this).val());
    alert(jQuery(this).find(":selected").text());
    window.location.assign("?version=" + jQuery(this).val());
});
```

This is my html code with a little django code:

```
<select id="date-version" name="selector">
    {% for ver in version_list %}
    <option value="{% if ver.version %}{{ ver.version }}{% endif %} "{% if version == ver.version %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
    {{ ver.user.person.name }} {{ ver.timestamp }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Can somebody tell why I can not display the selected option text after window.location.assign, and how that can be fixed, thanks :).

Comment: You are sending the data to django view. In view write version== code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
<select id="date-version" name="selector" value="{% request.GET.get('version', '') %}>
{% for ver in version_list %}
<option value="{% if ver.version %}{{ ver.version }}{% endif %} "{% if version == ver.version %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
{{ ver.user.person.name }} {{ ver.timestamp }}
</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi! Your code is not working. The problem is still the same.